# The link to the user profile shown in the message about a gained badge doesn't take to the right tab in the profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I got the message about a new badge, and when I clicked on the link to the profile page, I was taken to a page that doesn't list the recently gained badges. It was the activity tab, but the sub-tab is probably what I selected in my previous visit (although, I don't remember visiting that sub-tab).

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The page I was shown is not the page I see if I click on the user's profile link at the top of the page.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the next build, those links (only shown for badges) will take you to the badges tab with the recent sort.

Warning: there may be additional changes/improvements coming around those notifications, stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks. Is it expected behavior that the badge notification goes away on refresh even if you _don't_ click the close button? IIRC this was not the case beforehand (not sure).

Comment: @Manishearth - I wouldn't focus too much on how the notifications currently behave... :)

Comment: It [looks like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131224/link-in-badge-notification-points-to-stale-profile-page) the page the links currently point to is not updated in real time, so that the new badge may not yet be visible there.  Perhaps `?tab=activity&sort=badges` would be a better target after all?