# Badge Notification Banner "profile" link

Tags: bug, profile-page, notifications, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [The link to the user profile shown in the message about a gained badge doesn't take to the right tab in the profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113058/the-link-to-the-user-profile-shown-in-the-message-about-a-gained-badge-doesnt-t)

When clicking on the badge notification banner "See your [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=5&returnurl=%2Fusers%2F168974%3Ftab%3Dactivity)":

[image: screenshot1]

you are taken to the "activity" tab, but the sorting will remain at whatever you last had it at (sticky I think is the proper term for this?) so it is not immediately apparent that you even earned a badge:

[image: screenshot2]

The url currently used is:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=5&returnurl=/users/168974?tab=activity

I think it may be better if that link had `&sort=badges` at the end:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=5&returnurl=/users/168974?tab=activity&sort=badges

Or `&sort=all`:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=5&returnurl=/users/168974?tab=activity&sort=all

so you are taken directly to a page where you can learn more about the badge you just earned, why you earned it, etc..:

[image: screenshot3]

Comment: Or possibly `?tab=badges`?

Comment: @animuson Not a bad idea, but I personally like how the activity tab shows the timeline so you can see the context around how/when you got the badge.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to just change the badges area under the activity tab *to* the badges tab. Two separate areas for it seems very redundant. The only additional information it offers is the time you received it, which doesn't warrant a separate area.