# "New badge" link points to `tab=activity`

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The link to the user profile shown in the message about a gained badge doesn't take to the right tab in the profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113058/the-link-to-the-user-profile-shown-in-the-message-about-a-gained-badge-doesnt-t)

Basically, whenever a user gets a new badge, one sees:

> Congratulations! You recieved the `<badge>` badge for `<link-to-question>`. See your `[profile][link-to-activity-tab].`

(Or something like that, haven't got any pending badges so I can't check)

Now, the [profile] link links to `/users/<userid>/<username>?tab=activity`.

The issue is, `tab=activity` automagically chooses the last used `sort` option.

[image]

This means that you click the profile link and are left scratching your head where the shiny badge went.

Fix: Simple. Link to `/users/<userid>/<username>?tab=activity&sort=badges` OR `/users/<userid>/<username>?tab=activity&sort=all` (I think the intended behavior is the latter.)

Comment: Why not just [tab=badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=badges)?

Comment: @lunboks: Then it ought to be `tab=badges&sort=recent`, same issue.